# Sequence of integer (in ascending or descending order)

Tags: java

A sequence of whole numbers, check if it is ordered `true` (in ascending or descending order), otherwise it is `false`. If a number has the same value as the number below, it will not break the order. The sequence ends with `0`.

```
Sample Input 1: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
Sample Output 1:true
--------------------------------
Sample Input 2: 1 2 3 3 9 0
Sample Output 2:true
--------------------------------
Sample Input 3: 1 2 5 5 2 3 0
Sample Output 3: false
--------------------------------
```

I need help, I've been trying for days ... I really appreciate any help ...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 0;
        while (s.hasNextInt()) {
            int i = s.nextInt();
            a = i;
            if (i < a) {
                if (i < a) {
                    System.out.println("true");
                } else if (i > a) {
                    System.out.println("false");
                    break;
                }
            } else if (i > a) {
                if (i > a) {
                    System.out.println("true");
                } else if (i < a) {
                    System.out.println("false");
                    break;
                }
            } else if (i == a) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify what the problem is. Don't just dump requirements, code and "I need help"

Comment: you just need first to compare the two first numbers to know if ascending or descending then to compare from the second up to the last knowing the expected order. Of course if first numbers equals see more to know the order

Comment: *The sequence ends with 0* you do not follow that. Just after doing `a = i;` why to do `if (i < a){..}else if (i > a){}` and worst if I can say `else if (i == a)` which is true for 2 reasons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Based on the first two inputs (you will need a counter variable e.g. `count`), decide whether the remaining numbers should be in ascending order or in descending order. You can use a `boolean` variable e.g. `asc` to store this result i.e. if the second number is greater than the first number, the value of `asc` will be `true`; otherwise, `false`.
2. Once you have decided the value of `asc` from the first two numbers, you need to check if the next number follows this pattern or not. If the next number doesn't follow the pattern, print `false` and break the processing.
3. For every number that the scanner reads, you also need to check if it is `0`. If yes, print `true` and break the processing. Also, since your requirement mentions, *"If a number has the same value as the number below, it will not break the order."*, simply `continue` when the number read by the scanner has the same value as the last read number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean asc = true;
        int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (count < 2) {
                i = s.nextInt();
                if (i == 0) {
                    System.out.println(true);
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            } else {
                // Store the last input to `i` and read a new number into `j`
                i = j;
                j = s.nextInt();

                // Continue if the new number has the same value as the last read number
                if (i == j) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.println(true);
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }
            if (count <= 2) {
                j = s.nextInt();

                // Continue if the new number has the same value as the last read number
                if (i == j) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.println(true);
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }

            // Based on the first two inputs decide whether the remaining numbers should be
            // in ascending order or in descending order.
            if (count == 2 && j < i) {
                asc = false;
            }

            // Check if the next number (i.e. the value of `j`) follows this pattern or not
            if ((asc == true && j < i) || (asc == false && j > i)) {
                System.out.println(false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
true
```

**Another sample run:**

```
1 2 3 3 9 0
true
```

**Another sample run:**

```
1 2 5 5 2 3 0
false
```

**Another sample run:**

```
9 9 8 0
true
```

**Another sample run:**

```
5 5 6 0
true
```

Comment: This fails on descending sequences that start with repeated numbers e.g. "9 9 8 0" should be true.

Comment: I tried that code and it has an error in it:

 Sample Input 3:

1 2 5 5 2 3 0
Sample Output 3:

false

When I am entering number in number 2 it prints false, and it does not accept 3 and 0, that 0 is the one that should break the code

Answer (score 2):

I will not tell you the code as that would not be of much help but I can help with the approach you need to take.

1. With first 2 inputs assess if the pattern will be increasing or
   decreasing.
2. Then with the pattern check if the number is always = or less/greater than the number
3. Check for the last value. It must be 0 but it may or may not be according to pattern (in some cases it may come as the correct pattern itself confusing if it is a valid number or end of list)
4. If last number is not 0 then the output should be false.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your code like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int prev = sc.nextInt();
int curr = sc.nextInt();

while (sc.hasNextInt() && prev == curr) {
    prev = curr;
    curr = sc.nextInt();
}

boolean flag = prev < curr;

while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    prev = curr;
    curr = sc.nextInt();

    if (prev < curr && flag) {
        System.out.println("Ascending");
    } else if (prev > curr && !flag) {
        System.out.println("Descending");
    } else if (prev == curr) {
        System.out.println("Equal");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not sorted");
        break;
    }
}
```

You can put this in a method and `return false` from the `else` and `return true` from the end of the method.

Comment: This fails on ascending sequences that start with repeated numbers e.g. "1 1 2 0" should be true.

Comment: How about "1 1 2"? This still reports "Not sorted". Repeated numbers are explicitly allowed - "If a number has the same value as the number below, it will not break the order". No reason why they couldn't be at the start of the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

I assume 0 can't appear anywhere but at the end.

```
static boolean ordered(Scanner s)
{
    int curr, prev;
    curr = prev = s.nextInt();

    while(s.hasNextInt() && (curr = s.nextInt()) == prev);

    if(curr < prev)
        while(s.hasNextInt() && (curr = s.nextInt()) <= prev) prev = curr;
    else
        while(s.hasNextInt() && (curr = s.nextInt()) >= prev) prev = curr;

    return curr == 0;
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    test("0");
    test("1 0");
    test("1 1 0");
    test("9 9 8 7 6 6 5 4 3 2 1 0");
    test("1 1 2 3 3 3 9 0");
    test("1 2 5 5 2 3 0");
    test("9 8 7 6 7 8 9 0");        
}

static void test(String str)
{
    System.out.format("%s : %b%n", str, ordered(new Scanner(str)));
}
```

Output:

```
0 : true
1 0 : true
1 1 0 : true
9 9 8 7 6 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 : true
1 1 2 3 3 3 9 0 : true
1 2 5 5 2 3 0 : false
9 8 7 6 7 8 9 0 : false
```

Answer (score 1):

The above code is failing on one test condition.
Test Condition:
4 4 1 2 3 0

Minor change needed in the above code i.e, if (i == j && i<j)
So the code will look like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean asc = true;
        int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (count < 2) {
                i = s.nextInt();
                if (i == 0) {
                    System.out.println(true);
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            } else {

                i = j;
                j = s.nextInt();

                if (i == j) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.println(true);
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }
            if (count <= 2) {
                j = s.nextInt();
 
                if (i == j && i < j) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (j == 0) {
                    System.out.println(true);
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }

            if (count == 2 && j < i) {
                asc = false;
            }
            if ((asc == true && j < i) || (asc == false && j > i)) {
                System.out.println(false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```