# Program that reads a sequence of integer and outputs true if sequence is ordered in ascending or descending

Tags: java

I have been having problems with an exercise, what this asks me is this:

Write a program that reads a sequence of integer numbers and outputs true if the sequence is ordered (in ascending or descending order), otherwise, false. Keep in mind, if a number has the same value as the following number, it does not break the order.

The sequence ends with 0. Do not consider this number as a part of the sequence. The sequence always has at least one number (excluding 0).

Sample Input 1:

9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
Sample Output 1:

true
Sample Input 2:

1 2 3 3 9 0
Sample Output 2:

true
Sample Input 3:

1 2 5 5 2 3 0
Sample Output 3:

false

The code I have, to solve this, I have an error in it.

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int as = 0;
    int ds = 0;
    int eq = 0;
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int a;
    int num = sc.nextInt();
   for(int  i = 1 ;i < n ; i++)
    {
       a = sc.nextInt();
       while(a != 0)
       {
           if (a < num)                 ////// descending order
           {
               num = a;
               ds = 1;
               break;
           }
           else if ( a == num )                 ////////equal
           {
               num = a;
               eq = 1;
               break;
           }
           else                                        //////////ascending order
           {
               num = a;
               as = 1;
               break;
           }
       }
    }
  if(ds == 1 && as ==1 && eq==1 )
   {
       System.out.println("false");
   }
  else if ( (as == 1 && eq ==1) || ds ==0)
   {
       System.out.println("true");
   }
  else if ( (ds ==1 && eq==1) || as ==0)
   {
       System.out.println("true");
   }
}
```

I have checked my code and the task shows fail in the 3rd test. The task is showing my output is true whereas my output is coming false. I have run my code everywhere it is showing false. Why is this happening?

Something dirty my code, would you accept an easier and shorter way to solve this problem or tell me what my mistake could be, please, thank you very much for your time and answers

Comment: This has been answered [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61567900/6438819)

Comment: Thanks, but try that code and it has an error in:

 Sample Input 3:

1 2 5 5 2 3 0
Sample Output 3:

false

When I am entering number in number 2 it prints false, and it does not accept 3 and 0, that 0 is the one that should break the code

Comment: Even your sample input is exactly the same as the duplicate question. There are multiple upvoted solutions there, I am sure at least one of them is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the constraints of your exercise, but i would do something like this.
Get all the values from your input at one time, this way it avoids nesting loops which can create confusion. Then if the last element is 0 remove it. Lastly, Store the sorted versions of the list in 2 separate lists, and compare the original to those.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
int n = sc.nextInt();
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    sequence.add(sc.nextInt());
}

if(sequence.get(sequence.size() - 1) == 0){
    sequence.remove(sequence.size() - 1);
}

List<Integer> ascOrder = new ArrayList<>(sequence);
Collections.sort(ascOrder);

List<Integer> descOrder = new ArrayList<>(sequence);
Collections.sort(descOrder,Collections.reverseOrder());

boolean isOrdered = sequence.equals(ascOrder) || sequence.equals(descOrder);
System.out.println(String.valueOf(isOrdered));
```